# how to show a context menu on a Dynamic HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery and want to develop a context menu having only "Edit" and "cancel" functionality. I have a dynamic HTML Table.

I want to show the context menu only for 2nd  for a (Except Header i.e. "Statement")
Table structure is following:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td>ID</td>
     <td>Statement</td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>Select * From mytable.</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>Select * From table.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>3</td>
       <td> Delte tabel mytable.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Truncate table mytable</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>5</td>
        <td>Truncate table mytable</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I want a functionality, if I click on the "Statement"(Except Header) column then context menu should display. Thanking you in anticipation guys..... Kapil